# How can I retrieve posts with featured images from a WordPress database if WordPress is no longer installed?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a WordPress database in MySQL, but no longer have WordPress installed. How can I retrieve the posts and their featured images using only PHP and MySQL?

Comment: see this link:https://wordpress.org/support/topic/retrieveing-featured-image-url

Comment: @Suchit that's using WP code, not regular php

Comment: Why do you need to write your own code? If there's an existing function, you should use it.

Comment: i no lo nger have a WP install on my server, i just have the sql tables with lot of content /posts i need to show

Comment: If you don't have WP installed, are you sure the featured images are even still there? They would have been in wp-content/uploads, so finding their reference may be a fool's errand if it points to nowt.

Comment: yes they are there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be [MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

```
<?php

$wp_database = new mysqli("yourhost", "yourusername", "yourpasssword", "yourdatabase");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Here's how you get all the posts. Adjust table names to suit.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_status` LIKE 'publish' AND `post_type` LIKE 'post'";

$result =  mysqli_query($wp_database, $sql);

$posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_free_result($result);
foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
<div>
    <?php print_r($post); ?>
</div>

<?php endforeach;

// And here's how you get an individual image url.

$post_id = 1181; // Your post ID here

$sql = "SELECT `guid` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT  `meta_value` 
FROM  `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE  `meta_key` LIKE  '_thumbnail_id'
AND  `post_id` = $post_id)";

$result = mysqli_query($wp_database, $sql);
$images = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_free_result($result);
foreach ($images as $image): ?>
<div>
    <?php print_r($image); ?>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: thanks! yeeeees! this is it! it works!!!