# PHP Array values are correct but not displayed correct

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I've been trying to combine two database queries in to one. Now I've finally done this (yeah). But One problem keeps me from completing this task. And I bet its really simple but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've a database query set-up and it works.

```
    $sql = "SELECT `guid` FROM `pf_posts` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT  `meta_value`
    FROM  `pf_postmeta`
    WHERE  `meta_key` LIKE  '_thumbnail_id'
    AND  `post_id` = $post_id)";

    $result = mysqli_query($wp_database, $sql);
    $images = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    foreach ($images as $image): ?>
        <div>
             <?php print_r($image); ?>
        </div>    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This get's me the correct value BUT in a `print_r` which get's me this:

```
Array ( [guid] => http://mydomein.nl/wp-content/images-001.jpg )
```

But I would like to remove the `Array ( [guid] =>` and the last `)` part from the print_r.

I've looked into string replace but I have no idea how to set correct. I would like to be able to `echo` it. I've gotten the code for the database from here:
[How can I retrieve posts with featured images from a WordPress database if WordPress is no longer installed? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548609/7636455)

Comment: Oh man your my hero! finally!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) will print a human-readable representation of the argument. In your case, `$image` is an `array` with one element, key "guid" and value "http://mydomein.nl/wp-content/images-001.jpg".

So, what you need to do is just `echo` the element you want:

```
<?php
foreach ($images as $image): ?>
    <div>
            <?php echo $image["guid"] ?>
    </div>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<?php print_r($image['guid']); ?>
```